# IF formula for conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, if

I am looking at using IF on conditional formatting but can't seem to get it to work.

What I am after is:

- IF C7 Contains any text, then input conditional formatting.
- IF cell has no text and is blank do not input conditional formatting.

I am placing this conditional formatting on, say, cell C17 to reflect what is inputted on cell C7.

I don't want the formula to be based on specific text, just any input that is placed in Cell C7.

[image]

Comment: Which formula have you tried ?

Comment: In your diagram, which cell represents the `C7` cell you mention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a formula rule.

In a conditional formatting formula rule, if the formula evaluates to TRUE, the formatting will be applied.

In your case, you create the rule with C17 selected and enter a formula like

```
=C7<>""
```

This formula means "If C7 is not blank", which satisfies your condition of C7 containing any text.

[image]

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly for what I needed :)